# Why is there such a difference between chi2 and mcnemar?

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared, statistical-test

With R, I run these two tests and get very different results. Does anyone have any explanations?
Thanks in advance!

## Here is the code:

```
response_distribution <- matrix(c(1298, 818,    # Number of "No" and "YES" in condition "High" 
                                  4176, 2682),  # Number of "No" and "YES" in condition "Low"
                                nrow = 2,       # Number of conditions
                                byrow = TRUE,   # Fill matrix by rows
                                dimnames = list(c("High", "Low"), c("0", "1")))

chisq.test(response_distribution)
mcnemar.test(response_distribution)
```

## Here is the result:

```
> chisq.test(response_distribution)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  response_distribution
X-squared = 0.11924, df = 1, p-value = 0.7299

> mcnemar.test(response_distribution)

    McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction

data:  response_distribution
McNemar's chi-squared = 2256.6, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

I wanted to do a mcnemar (because the subjects are matched) but the result is so different from chi2 that I have my doubts.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76875/what-is-the-difference-between-mcnemars-test-and-the-chi-squared-test-and-how? More generally, this appears to be a question about statistics, not about programming, so I am voting to migrate this question to Cross Validated.